# Does multiple units means multiple connection strings in Azure IoT hub and Event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventhub

Are connection strings independent of the number of units we create in IoT hub and throughput units in Event hub?
Will there be only one connection string for single IoT hub and multiple units are create only when scaling is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units determine how many messages the IoT Hub/Event Hub can handle in a time period.
So it decides the *scale*.
More units mean it can handle more data, but it also costs more.

Quote from [Event Hubs docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-about#key-architecture-components):

> Throughput units: Pre-purchased units of capacity that control the throughput capacity of Event Hubs.

Quote from [Iot Hub pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/):

> Number of units depends on number of messages required for your IoT solution. For example, each unit of S1 or B1 IoT Hub can handle 400,000 messages a day.

Comment: And does the no of units affect number of connection strings?

Comment: No, it does not.